# Override PHP docblock/annotation of method without overloading (PhpStorm autocompletion)

Tags: php, autocomplete, phpstorm, docblocks

*This is a question about the autocompletion behavior in PhpStorm (and possibly other IDEs) in conjunction with PHP docblocks.*

I have to groups of classes in my application. First there are individual classes for various **products** (CarProduct, FoodProduct etc.), all inheriting from BaseProduct, and the counterpart for individual **contracts** (CarContract, FoodContract etc.), all inheriting from BaseContract.

```
<?php

class BaseContract
{
    /** @var BaseProduct */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @return BaseProduct
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }
}
```

Now I have an instance of **CarContract**, and I wanna get some **CarProduct** specific information:

```
<?php

/* PhpStorm thinks, this is BaseProduct */
$product = $carContract->getProduct();

/* hence, getSpeed() is not available for PhpStorm */
$product->getSpeed();
```

The autocompletion is not working as I like. There are two workarounds for this, but both are not nice:

1. Overload *getProduct()* in the subclass, just with updated `@return` docblocks
2. Add `/** @var CarProduct $product */` everywhere, where I access the product of a CarContract

Is there a "usual" way to solve something like this, or are my workarounds the only solutions?

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm does not really allow/does not support doing something like: have the same named class defined elsewhere and just use it as a reference for overriding definitions of real class. You can do that .. but IDE will warn with "multiple definitions of the same class" and it may introduce some weird behaviour/unexpected warnings...

Here is a ticket that ask for such feature: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-851 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Your options are: you can provide correct type hint locally (to local variable) using `@var` -- you already know it and that's first that you would think of:

```
<?php

/** @var \CarProduct $product */
$product = $carContract->getProduct();

$product->getSpeed();
```

---

Another possible way: instead of overriding actual method .. you can try doing the same but with `@method` PHPDoc -- will work with your code:

```
<?php
/**
 * My Car Product class
 * 
 * @method \CarProduct getProduct() Bla-bla optional description
 */
class CarContract extends BaseContract ...
```

Comment: The second way looks nice and would also work. Yet, all of the three ways have their pros and cons, but thank you for your detailed feedback!