# PhpStorm not recognizing return type as extension of another

Tags: php, phpstorm, type-hinting, php-7.1

**Scenario**

I'm using PHP7 type hinting to say that my function has return type `City`.

```
public function getCityById(int $city_id) : City { ... }
```

In this function, I return the outcome of running a finder.

```
return $this->city_finder->findById($city_id);
```

But PhpStorm complains here, because the `findById()` function returns `AbstractModel`.

But I have `class City extends AbstractModel`, so this isn't a problem. PhpStorm doesn't seem to recognize this, however, and highlights the return statement with a warning.

I don't want to mute this type of warning (disable inspection), because it is an important warning to have.

**Question**

Can I make PhpStorm recognize that this return statement will satisfy the return type?

**Additional info**

One workaround is to extract a variable, and annotate it, like so:

```
/** @var City $city */
$city = $this->city_finder->findById($city_id);
return $city;
```

At this point, it stops warning me about it, but it seems like the extra line should be avoidable since it only exists to mute a warning in the IDE.

The `findById()` function is protected against returning the wrong type, because a Finder class is generated on a per-model basis.

```
$this->city_finder = $this->orm->getFinder(City::class);
//...
$city = $city_finder->findById(...);
```

Comment: You can try overriding the signature of `findById()` method for your `city_finder` class (using `@method` tag in PHPDoc comment for that class) and tell that this method returns concrete `City` class (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112745/783119). Another idea -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44913283/783119 (not sure if it will be applicable here though)

Answer (score 4):

PHPStorm is correct.

Your `findById()` returns `AbstractModel` and it is more broad that `City` that you're trying to return. In a case if you'll receive from `findById()` some other class that is also inherited from `AbstractModel`, but is not a `City` or its descendant - you will receive fatal error from PHP and it is what PHPStorm warns you about.

You can workaround this by either adding annotation, as you do already or by explicitly checking `if ($city instanceof City) {return $city; }`. It may look slightly bloated by will be safe in runtime.

Comment: Actually, we're secured against this, because my Finder class is generated on a per-model basis. E.g. `$finder = $orm->getFinder(City::class);`. But I can see that it would be very hard for PHPStorm to detect this.

Comment: @Alec That's not just very hard for PHPStorm to know, it's impossible, without a special rule for that ORM. As far as the type system's concerned, `City::class` is just a string you're using in the constructor, it doesn't change the type of object constructed.

Comment: @IMSoP True .. PhpStorm's [Advanced Metadata functionality](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata) is helping in other cases... but I doubt that it will do anything here (as this one works differently -- looks like) -- the `$finder` might be the same class instance for `City` and `Area` and hold all nuances (difference) internally.

Answer (score 3):

PHPStorm is technically right here: according to the contracts of your functions, the statement might return the wrong value.

```
$result = $this->city_finder->findById($city_id);
```

The only thing we can know about `$result` here is what `findById` promises us, and that's that it's an `AbstractModel`. It *might* be a `City`, but it might equally be a `User`, or a `Widget`, or an anonymous object defined as `class extends AbstractModel {}`.

The underlying problem is that `$this->city_finder` is an instance of some abstract repository; while *you* know that it will always handle `City` objects, that's not actually built into your type system. If it was a more specific class, it could declare that it returned `City` objects from its `findById` method, and the code would be type safe.

---

Based on your comment that your ORM takes in the class name as a parameter (`$finder = $orm->getFinder(City::class);`), if PHP supported "generics" or "template meta-programming", you might write something like this:

```
class ORM {
    public function getFinder<T>(): Finder<T> { ... }
}
class Finder<T> {
     public function findById(int $id): T { ...}
}
$finder = $orm->getFinder<City>();
$city = $finder->findById($city_id);
```

The analyser would know that `$finder` was an instance of `Finder<City>`, and therefore that `findById` would return a `City`.

Without generics, though, there is no way to tell the analyser that if given `City::class` in its constructor, the `Finder` class will always return instances of that class.